# Why does std::move take a forward reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue, forwarding-reference

The implementation of `std::move` basically looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&
move(T&& t)
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t);
}
```

Note that the parameter of `std::move` is a universal reference (also known as a forwarding reference, but we're not forwarding here). That is, you can `std::move` both lvalues and rvalues:

```
std::string a, b, c;
// ...
foo(std::move(a));       // fine, a is an lvalue
foo(std::move(b + c));   // nonsense, b + c is already an rvalue
```

But since the whole point of `std::move` is to cast to an rvalue, why are we even allowed to `std::move` rvalues? Wouldn't it make more sense if `std::move` would only accept lvalues?

```
template<typename T>
T&&
move(T& t)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

Then the nonsensical expression `std::move(b + c)` would cause a compile-time error.

The above implementation of `std::move` would also be much easier to understand for beginners, because the code does exactly what it appears to do: It takes an lvalue and returns an rvalue. You don't have to understand universal references, reference collapsing and meta functions.

So why was `std::move` designed to take both lvalues and rvalues?

Comment: My quick guess would be that when you write code to move things around you don't want to be constantly thinking whether your variables are lvalues or rvalues, you just want to do it.

Comment: Because it is designed to cast both lvalue and rvalue to rvalue unconditionally.

Comment: @6502 This question or the details of it are more useful for a library developer than application developer. Application developer can just happily call std::move(); and get on with the work. Of course should understand that moving the local variable would make the state invalid. Otherwise nothing to break the head here.

Comment: @Jagannath: mine was just a rant about the very sad state of this C++ part. We simply got more possibilities for undefined behavior and complex semantic with special cases (and THAT is the problem of C++, not speed).

Comment: @6502 And rants don't belong on stack overflow, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: As I understand it, inside a template function that takes a "universal reference" you don't know whether it will bind to an r-value or an l-value so maybe that's why `std::move` needs to accept both.

Comment: In generic code sometimes you do not know if an expression is an lvalue or an rvalue (function calls, for instance), but may want to unconditionally move from it. Also, allowing the quasi-identity rvalue-to-rvalue cast isn't dangerous, so there isn't a compelling reason to prohibit it. But I suspect only Howard Hinnant knows the *real* reason...

Comment: @Galik this is a bit of a misconception. When you apply `std::move(x)` inside some  `template <T> f(T&& x)`, then `x` is a lvalue of type rvalue reference (in case a rvalue was passed). So you actually apply `std::move` on a lvalue in this case. But I guess the problem appears when doing something like `std::move(f())`, and you may not know whether `f` returns a lvalue reference or a rvalue.

Comment: i guess because convenience!we don't worry about rvalue or lvalue or a lvalue of type ravalue reference.....

Comment: @6502: I agree with you I am myself not yet familiar with these constructs but it seems C++ is adding more complexity into the language, whereas it was uneccessary

Comment: @Giorgi Unfortunately move semantics was quite necessary. If you think otherwise, ponder on `std::auto_ptr` and try to implement a working solution to that problem without move semantics.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Playing devil's advocate here (I definitely don't agree with Giorgi and 6502's opinion). Don't allow copying or assigning at all of `auto_ptr`, and just give it a move member function which transfers ownership to another `auto_ptr`. Then you can move it out of a function via a reference parameter. Is that the problem you are referring to?

Comment: @juanchopanza: in language where you can trigger UB easily(?)-you should strive to minimize cases when that happens instead of introducing new features which can introduce UB (I agreed with 6502 only on this point, I don't even refer specifically to move semantics, I am not familiar with it).

Comment: @Giorgi I may be missing something, but I'm not sure how rvalue references introduce UB beyond what was already possible in C++03. I do agree that the language is overly complex, but unfortunately it isn't possible to get rid of "old" complexity that doesn't buy you much. I think the extra complexity in rvalue references is warranted. Obviously that is my personal opinion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is some example simplified to the extreme:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
T&& my_move(T& t)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<bool> v{true};

    std::move(v[0]); // std::move on rvalue, OK
    my_move(v[0]);   // my_move on rvalue, OOPS
}
```

Cases like the one above may appear in generic code, for example when using containers which have specializations that return proxy objects (rvalues), and you may not know whether the client will be using the specialization or not, so you want unconditional support for move semantics.

Comment: Upvoted.  Here is a real-world example: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L2451

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't hurt.

You're simply establishing a guarantee that code will treat the result as an rvalue. You certainly could write std::move in such way that it errors out when dealing with something that's already an rvalue, but what is the benefit?

In generic code, where you don't necessarily know what type(s) you're going to be working with, what gains in expressiveness would you extract out of a bunch of "if type is rvalue do nothing else std::move" plastered everywhere when you can simply say "I promise we can think of this as an rvalue".

You said it yourself, it is nothing more than a cast. Should *_cast operations also fail if the argument already matches the intended type?

Comment: That final sentence is very convincing. Good job. +1