# Are there any use cases for std::forward with a prvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

The most common usage of `std::forward` is to, well, perfect forward a forwarding (universal) reference, like

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(param)); // perfect forward to g
}
```

Here `param` is an `lvalue`, and `std::forward` ends up casting it to a rvalue or lvalue, depending on what the argument that bounded to it was.

Looking at the [definition of `std::forward` from cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) I see that there is also a `rvalue` overload

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t );
```

Can anyone give me any reason why the `rvalue` overload? I cannot see any use case. If you want to pass a rvalue to a function, you can just pass it as is, no need to apply `std::forward` on it.

This is different from `std::move`, where I see why one wants also a `rvalue` overload: you may deal with generic code in which you don't know what you're being passed and you want unconditional support for move semantics, see e.g. [Why does std::move take a universal reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28936258/3093378).

**EDIT** To clarify the question, I'm asking why [overload (2) from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is necessary, and a use case for it.

Comment: There are use cases for forwarding rvalues as rvalues. See [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html).

Comment: Is it to prevent rvalues being forwarded as lvalues without using a bunch of extra enable_if conditions? (see case C [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html))

Comment: @wakjah how can the rvalue be forwarded as lvalue? If you call `f( prvalue )`, where `prvalue` is something like `get_value()`, then you pass a `rvalue`, no need to forward it. Maybe I'm not getting what you meant.

Comment: @vsoftco from what the page I linked says, the undesirable effect is perhaps more accurately described as forwarding a rvalue *to* an lvalue, or storing an lvalue reference to an rvalue - which some possible implementations of `std::forward` make it easier to do than others

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29135698/241631) even though that one isn't specifically asking about the rvalue overload in the question itself. Howard talks of the rationale behind it, and I have a very contrived example that shows it in action.

Comment: @Praetorian yes I've seen the linked question, I understand how it works via the ref. collapsing rules, I just wasn't able to come up with a "good" use case for the rvalue overload.

Comment: Case B from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html is the answer.

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041246/in-stdforward-how-does-it-accept-rvalue

Comment: @evan almost... I emailed Scott Meyers about this issue, and his answer was that the rvalue overload is just left out of the book, since he couldn't think of a real usage case for it. That's why I asked here about a real-life usage case.

Comment: For the perfect forwarding? Say you implement a factory function template that returns shared_ptr<T>, based on the fact that `rvalue reference` is not a rvalue. I'm not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: yes factory template returning shared_ptr<T> is the perfect example, I used that alreay 2 years ago in my framework ( link directly here the factory function (line 80): https://github.com/Darelbi/Infectorpp/blob/master/include/Infectorpp/InfectorTraits.hpp
surprising Scott meyers didn't think about that.

Comment: @DarioOO thanks for the link. Can you maybe write a succinct answer? From your example it's still not clear for me why does `std::forward` need to be also defined for rvalues.

Comment: Answered in my comment to my answer, should I have to edit the comment back into the answer to get accepted? :)

Comment: So far have you solved the problem? I think ther's more than one answer that address it now :)

Comment: @DarioOO Sorry, was quite busy with other things these days. Will take a look and of course if the answer(s) address the issue will accept.

Comment: One question for you: why would you call f to forward arguments to g, instead of calling g directly?

Answer (score 1):

Ok since @vsoftco asked for concise use case here's a refined version (using his idea of having "my_forward" to actually see wich overload gets called).

I interpret "use case" by providing a code sample that without prvalue not compile or behave differently (regardless of that would be really usefull or not).

We have [2 overloads for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501400/the-implementation-of-stdforward) `std::forward`

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
inline T&& my_forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout<<"overload 1"<<std::endl;
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template <class T>
inline T&& my_forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout<<"overload 2"<<std::endl;
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
              "Can not forward an rvalue as an lvalue.");
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

And we have 4 possible use cases

**Use case 1**

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Library
{
    vector<int> b;
public:
    // &&
    Library( vector<int>&& a):b(std::move(a)){

    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    Library a( my_forward<vector<int>>(v)); // &
    return 0;
}
```

**Use case 2**

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Library
{
    vector<int> b;
public:
    // &&
    Library( vector<int>&& a):b(std::move(a)){

    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    Library a( my_forward<vector<int>>(std::move(v))); //&&
    return 0;
}
```

**Use case 3**

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Library
{
    vector<int> b;
public:
    // &
    Library( vector<int> a):b(a){

    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    Library a( my_forward<vector<int>>(v)); // &
    return 0;
}
```

**Use case 4**

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Library
{
    vector<int> b;
public:
    // &
    Library( vector<int> a):b(a){

    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    Library a( my_forward<vector<int>>(std::move(v))); //&&
    return 0;
}
```

**Here's a resume**

1. Overload 1 is used, without it you get compilation error
2. **Overload 2 is used, without it you get compilation error**
3. Overload 1 is used, wihtout it you get compilation error
4. Overload 2 is used, without it you get compilation error

---

Note that if we do not use forward

```
Library a( std::move(v));
//and
Library a( v);
```

you get:

1. Compilation error
2. **Compile**
3. Compile
4. **Compile**

As you see, if you use only one of the two `forward` overloads, you basically cause to not compile 2 out of 4 cases, while if you do not use `forward` at all you would get to compile only 3 out of 4 cases.

Comment: thinking to the complexity forward hides, I would call it "imperfect forwarding" instead.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for answering comment by @vsoftco

> @DarioOO thanks for the link. Can you maybe write a succinct answer? From your example it's still not clear for me why does std::forward need to be also defined for rvalues

**In short:**

Because without a rvalue specialization the following code would not compile

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Library
{
    vector<int> b;
public:
    // hi! only rvalue here :)
    Library( vector<int>&& a):b(std::move(a)){

    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    A a( forward<vector<int>>(v));
    return 0;
}
```

---

however I can't resist to type more so here's also the not succint version of the answer.

**Long version:**

You need to move `v` because the class `Library` has no constructor accepting lvalue to it, but only a rvalue reference. 
Without perfect forwarding we would end up in a undesired behaviour:

> wrapping functions would incurr high performance penality when passing heavy objects.

with move semantics we make sure that move constructor is used IF POSSIBLE.
In the above example if we remove `std::forward` the code will not compile.

So what is actually doing `forward`? moving the element without our consensus? Nope!

It is just creating a copy of the vector and moving it. How can we be sure about that? Simply try to access the element.

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
A a( forward<vector<int>>(v)); //what happens here? make a copy and move
std::cout<<v[0];     // OK! std::forward just "adapted" our vector
```

if you instead move that element

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
A a( std::move(v)); //what happens here? just moved
std::cout<<v[0];  // OUCH! out of bounds exception
```

**So that overload is needed to make possible a implicit conversion that is still safe, but not possible without the overload.**

Infact the following code will just not compile:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
A a( v); //try to copy, but not find a lvalue constructor
```

---

**Real use case:**

You may argue that forwarding arguments may create useless copies and hence hide a possible performance hit, yes, that's actually true, but consider real use cases:

```
template< typename Impl, typename... SmartPointers>
static std::shared_ptr<void> 
    instancesFactoryFunction( priv::Context * ctx){
        return std::static_pointer_cast<void>( std::make_shared<Impl>(

                std::forward< typename SmartPointers::pointerType>( 
            SmartPointers::resolve(ctx))... 
            )           );
}
```

Code was taken from my framework (line 80): [Infectorpp 2](https://github.com/Darelbi/Infectorpp/blob/master/include/Infectorpp/InfectorTraits.hpp)

In that case arguments are forwarded from a function call. `SmartPointers::resolve`'s returned values are correctly moved regardless of the fact that constructor of `Impl` accept rvalue or lvalue (so no compile errors and those get moved anyway).

Basically you can use `std::foward` in any case in wich you want to make code simpler and more readable but you have to keep in mind 2 points

- extra compile time (not so much in reality)
- may cause unwanted copies (when you do not explicitly move something into something that require a rvalue)

If used with care is a powerfull tool.

Comment: Thanks, btw you should have `Library` instead of `A`. Will think about your example, especially about *forward making a copy then move*. AFAIK, `forward` is just casting with reference collapsing rules. But in any case, thanks again, will let you know soon what I think.

Comment: OK, look here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bce1b3c7e5d0237. I changed `forward` with my implementation called `my_forward`, which works **only for** lvalues. Your code still compiles. However, if you look at the [declaration of `std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), you see that there are 2 overloads: (1) and (2). (2) takes a prvalue. My question was why is (2) necessary and what is a usege case? As you can see, your code works with `my_forward` defined only for lvalues. Does it make sense what I'm asking?

Comment: In your case, `forward<vector<int>>(v)` is the same as `std::move(v)` (see the declaration and the reference collapsing rules). `v` itself is still a lvalue though (has a name).

Comment: Ah infact, my code use the first overload wich is I wanted to show, you meant the other overload. It is analoug, but with the 2nd overload you accept stuff that is explicitly moved (if you remove the first overload the code won't compile unless you move explicitly with std::move, removing the reference make impossible to implicitly move with 2nd overload only)

Comment: look here, it don't compile when moving with the other overload only
http://ideone.com/4Vvlnk and yes what you ask make much sense to me

Answer (score 0):

I stared at this question before, read Howard Hinnant's link, couldn't fully grok it after an hour of thinking. Now I was looking and got the answer in five minutes. (Edit: got the answer is too generous, as Hinnant's link had the answer. I meant that I understood, and was able to explain it in a simpler way, which hopefully someone will find helpful).

Basically, this allows you to be generic in certain kinds of situations depending on the typed that's passed in. Consider this code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class GoodBye
{
  double b;
 public:
  GoodBye( double&& a):b(std::move(a)){ std::cerr << "move"; }
  GoodBye( const double& a):b(a){ std::cerr << "copy"; }
};

struct Hello {
  double m_x;

  double & get()  { return m_x; }
};

int main()
{
  Hello h;
  GoodBye a(std::forward<double>(std::move(h).get()));
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints "move". What's interesting is that if I remove the `std::forward`, it prints copy. This, for me, is hard to wrap my mind around, but let's accept it and move on. (Edit: I suppose this happens because get will return a lvalue reference to an rvalue. Such an entity decays into an lvalue, but std::forward will cast it into an rvalue, just as in the common use of forward. Still feels unintuitive though).

Now, let's imagine another class:

```
struct Hello2 {
  double m_x;

  double & get() & { return m_x; }
  double && get() && { return std::move(m_x); }
};
```

Suppose in the code in `main`, `h` was an instance of Hello2. Now, we no longer need std::forward, because the call to `std::move(h).get()` returns an rvalue. However, suppose the code is generic:

```
template <class T>
void func(T && h) {
  GoodBye a(std::forward<double>(std::forward<T>(h).get()));
}
```

Now when we call `func`, we'd like it to work properly with both `Hello` and `Hello2`, i.e. we'd like to trigger a move. That only happens for an rvalue of `Hello` if we include the outer `std::forward`, so we need it. But... We got to the punchline. When we pass an rvalue of `Hello2` to this function, the rvalue overload of get() will already return an rvalue double, so `std::forward` is actually accepting an rvalue. So if it didn't, you wouldn't be able to write fully generic code as above.

Damn.

Comment: If the answer is your work, why do you have code similiar to my answer? (not to mention you include `<vector>` like in my answer but you do not use it :/ feels very much copypasting and editing, so why not editing directly instead? )..

Comment: It's not similar other than superficially. I copied and pasted your code into my ide initially because I was curious. Then I figured out the answer, and modified the code I already had there. I didn't edit your answer because it's not correct, it wouldn't be a minor modification to fix it.